How to Host videos and Images fast in Wordpress?
I want to represent video testinomial on my website and also there are lot of images in my website but I want to load these videos and images fast how can i do this?
I saw there are many sites using cdn that help them to load there images and videos faster any body have idea about this?
And if this method is ok then suggest me a cdn name?
Im trying to load videos and phtotos faster in wordpress.

I suggest you to use the CDN that will significantly improve the loading speed of images and videos on your WordPress website, enhancing the overall user experience.

Which cdn is best?

I suggest using Microsoft Azure CDN.
